# How to calculate the torque of this example?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was thinking a long time to solve this question .. I want to calculate the rope tension .. I want to use the torque to solve it ..

What I managed to do is the following :

$torque = ? - mg *cos(20) * 2/2 = 0$

as you see that $?$ is the missing part .. I tried different ways to calculate $?$ but I did not get the correct answer ..

[image]

The rope tension $T = 44.2 N$ according to my book ..

Thanks